# Trying to push changes from STAGING site to LIVE site (both WordPress) but I'm trying to figure out which database items to choose from

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb, custom-wordpress-pages, staging

I've cloned the existing [www.DOMAINHERE.com](http://www.DOMAINHERE.com) to a staging site staging.DOMAINHERE.com and made changes to the staging site such as its theme, its templates, its template parts, its blocks (added customized block templates), etc...

I'm trying to push the changes to the LIVE site, but I'm not sure exactly which database tables to include without it breaking the site. The LIVE version of the site has new posts that I do not want to overwrite.

Here's a list of all the tables I currently have on the staging site (ignore "VM4414:2" and the file sizes as I just copied them via the browser console):

```
VM4414:2 wp_bv_fw_requests - 16.00 KB
VM4414:2 wp_bv_ip_store - 272.00 KB
VM4414:2 wp_bv_lp_requests - 16.00 KB
VM4414:2 wp_commentmeta - 48.00 KB
VM4414:2 wp_comments - 96.00 KB
VM4414:2 wp_links - 32.00 KB
VM4414:2 wp_options - 160.00 KB
VM4414:2 wp_postmeta - 48.00 KB
VM4414:2 wp_posts - 80.00 KB
VM4414:2 wp_term_relationships - 32.00 KB
VM4414:2 wp_term_taxonomy - 48.00 KB
VM4414:2 wp_termmeta - 48.00 KB
VM4414:2 wp_terms - 48.00 KB
VM4414:2 wp_usermeta - 48.00 KB
VM4414:2 wp_users - 64.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_bwg_album - 2.26 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_bwg_album_gallery - 2.07 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_bwg_file_paths - 45.39 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_bwg_gallery - 3.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_bwg_image - 27.31 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_bwg_image_comment - 1.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_bwg_image_rate - 1.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_bwg_image_tag - 25.63 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_bwg_shortcode - 24.72 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_bwg_theme - 39.62 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_commentmeta - 79.62 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_comments - 30.07 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_links - 1.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_nf3_action_meta - 16.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_nf3_actions - 16.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_nf3_chunks - 16.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_nf3_field_meta - 64.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_nf3_fields - 16.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_nf3_form_meta - 16.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_nf3_forms - 16.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_nf3_object_meta - 64.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_nf3_objects - 16.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_nf3_relationships - 16.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_nf3_upgrades - 16.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_ngg_album - 1.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_ngg_gallery - 3.46 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_ngg_pictures - 64.82 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_options - 2.58 MB
VM4414:2 wpha_postmeta - 980.18 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_posts - 3.11 MB
VM4414:2 wpha_redirection_404 - 112.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_redirection_groups - 48.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_redirection_items - 112.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_redirection_logs - 64.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_smush_dir_images - 77.49 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_ssp_stats - 144.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_term_relationships - 26.05 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_term_taxonomy - 30.32 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_termmeta - 10.06 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_terms - 44.99 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_usermeta - 49.59 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_users - 8.27 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_wpstg_queue - 16.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_yoast_indexable - 672.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_yoast_indexable_hierarchy - 96.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_yoast_migrations - 32.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_yoast_primary_term - 48.00 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_yoast_seo_links - 142.93 KB
VM4414:2 wpha_yoast_seo_meta - 15.56 KB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sad to say, there's no clean and guaranteed-trouble-free way to do what you want. WordPress's database code creates unique `id` numbers for rows in its tables: Post ids, metadata ids, option ids, and so forth.  When you clone a site (to create a staging site) the two sites start operating independently and you're sure to have duplicate ids.

If you're a really skilful WordPress developer / operator you may be able to get this to work. But it will be a *lot* of work and require a lot of testing. So, you'll have the same problem as you do now, where the production site gets ahead of the staging site while you're testing.

If this were my project I'd do one of these things.

- Remake the staging site from the production site. Then put the production site into maintenance mode, make your changes to the staging site, and clone it back to the production site.
- Make a careful list of all the changes you made to your staging site.  Then make the same changes (themes, templates, blocks, etc) to your production site.

This could be much more convenient, but sadly it is not.

Comment: I was really afraid that this was the answer... Is it possible to pull the new posts/pages from the live site (since during production on the staging site, the client added new posts/pages via a podcast plugin [Seriously Simple Podcasts]), refresh the staging site with the new data, and then clone the staging site turning it into the live site, and deleting the old live site? Any way to do it as simply as possible? Thank you.

(It's cuz I've made many changes and updates to templates and template parts, as well as adding custom blocks to the editor and redoing all that work would be tedious)

Comment: So I've just used WordPress's Export and Import tool to refresh the staging site. I can basically just clone the staging site and make it the live site, deleting the current old live site! Hopefully, this was the best way forward. Appreciate the help nonetheless!